# Getting an "Undefined" error in console.log

Tags: javascript

Write a function called "getAllKeys" which returns an array of all the input object's keys.

Example input:

```
{
  name : 'Sam',
  age : 25,
  hasPets : true
}
```

Function's return value (output) :

```
['name', 'age', 'hasPets']
```

Do not use "Object.keys" to solve this prompt.

My solution is below.

```
function getAllKeys(obj) {
  var arrayToPrint = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    arrayToPrint.push(key);
  }
  console.log(arrayToPrint);
}

obj1 = {
  name : 'Sam',
  age : 25,
  hasPets : true
};

getAllKeys(obj1);
```

console output:

[image]

Can someone please explain, why I am getting this Undefined?

Comment: You don't `return` anything.

Comment: if you run this code in the console, then the final output is the result of `getAllKeys(obj1);` - which is `undefined` - because your function doesn't return anything - by the way, this is **not an error**

Comment: however, your `getAllKeys` function, rather than logging to console **SHOULD** return the array, so that the function is at all useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the function is not returning anything. A function will return undefined if it explicitly does not return a value.

You can return the `arrayToPrint` from the function and log `getAllKeys(obj1)`

```
function getAllKeys(obj) {
  var arrayToPrint = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    arrayToPrint.push(key);
  }
  return arrayToPrint; // changed here
}

obj1 = {
  name : 'Sam',
  age : 25,
  hasPets : true
};

console.log(getAllKeys(obj1)); // changed here
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/g450d7fq/)

Comment: This is right but their confusion is created by the fact that they are not logging the function's output. Its the console doing it itself. Their existing function does not meet the requirement of returning the array but it still works and console's undefined can be ignored

Comment: this code, if run in the console (which is what the OP is doing with their code) will produce exactly the same output in the console!! in fact, if you put the OP code in a jsfiddle, you would not get the `undefined` in their code either - so, the "undefined" is not because the function doesn't return anything - the "undefined" is because *that's how the developer tools console operates* - though that doesn't take away from the fact that *this is how the `getAllKeys` function should be written to be at all useful*